# setInterval and clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a dynamic progress bar which starts from 1% width and goes to 100% width;
Here is the function

```
const dynamicBar = (id)=>{
            let bar = document.getElementById(id);
            let width = 1;

            let id= setInterval(frame,10);
            function frame(){
                if(width>=100){
                    clearInterval(id);
                }
                else{
                    bar.style.width = width + "%";
                    width++;
                }
            }

        };
```

And the html part:

```
<div class="w3-light-grey">
    <div class="w3-red" style="width:20%;height:20px;" id="bar1">       
    </div>  
</div>

<button onClick="dynamicBar('bar1')" class="w3-button">Click Me</button>
```

but the function does not work. It works if i use var instead of let but i want to know how to do this using let keyword.

Comment: multiple uses of id as var name - you pass it into the function but declare a local var - probably what's causing it not to work, call the second one intervalId or something different

Comment: that was the problem. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` doesn't allow you to define something twice, so you need to use a different name. You had `id` for both your parameter and in line 5, which isn't allowed with `let`.

For example,

```
let var1 = true;
let var1 = false;
```

would throw an error, since it defines var1 twice. However, you can change the value.

```
let var1 = true;
var1 = false;
```

The code block above would work just fine. `let` is used so that you don't **accidentally** override a variable in a big program.

```js
const dynamicBar = (idName) => {
  let bar = document.getElementById(idName);
  let width = 1;

  let id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      bar.style.width = width + "%";
      width++;
    }
  }

};
```

```html
<div class="w3-light-grey">
  <div class="w3-red" style="width:20%;height:20px;background-color:red;" id="bar1">
  </div>
</div>

<button onClick="dynamicBar('bar1')" class="w3-button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are using var, your first Id is been overridden by your second id assignment, so it will not throw an error. but when you use let, it tends to keep the code integrity and says no.

as an example

```
var foo = "something" 
var foo = "another thing"

console.log(foo) //another thing
```

**but**

```
let foo = "something" 
let foo = "another thing"

give you this, "Identifier 'foo' has already been declared"
```

one more thing, is that use const for constant values.

instead of this

> let id = setInterval(frame, 10);

use

```
const interval = = setInterval(frame, 10);
```

make sure you clear interval inside fame

```
clearInterval(interval)
```

and your code will start working